# What is 'Personalmarketing'?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

I have been asked to check a translation from German into English where the term *Personalmarketing* has been rendered as *recruitment marketing*. This doesn't feel right to me.

I understand *Personalmarketing* to have something to do with recruitment with a focus on improving the company branding.

Is this correct and how might it be translated succinctly into English?

Comment: Denglish -> English. Awww!

Comment: "This doesn't feel right to me." - can you elaborate on whether it just sounds weird to you or whether you have any doubts it carries the same meaning?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper mainly because recruitment sounds like an activity whereas Personal is more of an entity.

Answer (score 2):

Its an artificial word that describes a **HR position,** specifically the one who is responsible for looking after the **Job advertisements** and sourcing of candidates (as opposed to doing payroll, compliance and disciplinary stuff)

It think **recruitment** would fit best in most circumstances. Context would help though ...

Comment: You mean just 'recruitment' and not 'recruitment marketing'?

Comment: @paul: Yes, *recruitment marketing* seems unusual to me - but then, I´m not a native English speaker. If you search for job-ads **Recuiter** seems to be the common term, so I imagine the Recruiter would work in recruitment? I found one reference for "Recruiter, Marketing"

Answer (score -2):

From Wikipedia:

Personnel marketing is understood as a cross-departmental function that draws on the instruments and content of all human resources functions in a target-group-related manner and promotes an integrative view across all interfaces.

Comment: Please include the link to the article, and use quote markup (`>`) to mark the content that is not your own :)

Comment: Is this your own translation of this German Wikipedia article's first line: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalmarketing ?